Connecting different IP addresses in different VMs in hyper-V
how to make  different vms having different ip addresses to talk to each other in hyperv

DC1 - IP: 192.168.0.10
DC2 - IP: 192.168.0.11
DC3 - IP: 192.168.1.10
DC4 - IP: 192.168.2.10

only dc1 & 2 are able to ping each other
I am using server 2022 on all machines with dns settings of DC1 ip as 192.168.0.10 on all the 4 machines. but unable to establish connectivity with dc3 and dc4

If you're setting these addresses manually, also set the subnet mask to 255.255.0.0 or the prefix length to 16, whichever applies to the command or method you're using. If you're using DHCP, configure your DHCP server data so it does the same thing.
